# antoniogarrote/rdfstore-js reusing blank node

Tags: javascript, node.js, rdfstore

I am using **rdfstore** in nodejs and I cannot figure out how to **reuse** Blank nodes. I need to use blank node more then just once.

Here is the code:

```
graph.add(rdf.createTriple(
   new rdf.api.BlankNode(id);
   rdf.createNamedNode(predicate)
   rdf.createBlankNode()
);
```

**id** is taken from previously entered blankNode "_:30" => "30"

I have checked created blank node and it is correct (with correct id). But when I look into db it has wrong one. It seems to be using some counter even I give him exact node.

**EDIT 1**

I have checked created triple and it looks as I want it. So problem must be somewhere in adding triple into graph/storing the triple.

Thanks for any help,

Michal.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you by any chance find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: I would not use rdfstore anymore. I have used it for two years now and we needed to hack is multiple times. No PRs were accepted, this project is dead.

Comment: My solution was to use Jena and java. I built REST web service and I have no problem with it. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is actually simple: Each call to `rdfstore.Store.insert` creates a `SPARQL INSERT` statement. And each separate `SPARQL` statement has its own set of unique blank nodes.

That said, the only solution for our problem is to collect the triples to add in an array and finally add them all in one go.

```js
var triples = [];
[...]
store.insert(store.rdf.createGraph(triples), 
  graph, 
  function(success, cnt) {
    if(success) console.log(cnt + ' triples successfully added.');
  });
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: this won't help if I need to add something a week after. For my purpose I need a specific model so it would not help me. Anyway, thanks for help.